# How make this session Get into another .php?edit<?php echo $result->id;?>

Tags: php, mysql, session

How make this Session can read another. when this session declare inside view-data.php, it can't get this session.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('../includes/config.php');

if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin']) == 0){   
    header('location:index.php');
} 
?>
```

This is the code to view data. I need that `id` to get all database inside another.

```
<td>
    <a href="view-data.php?edit=<?php echo $result->id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to Complete ?');">&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-pen"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

I try to declare `get from id` but it still doesn't show the result.

```
//Checking user login     
$npp = $_SESSION['alogin'];
$sql = "SELECT * from users where npp = (:npp);";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':npp', $npp, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  
foreach($results as $result) {    
    $Snama=htmlentities($result->name);
    $Sjob=htmlentities($result->job);
    $SOffice=htmlentities($result->office);    
}    
<a><?php echo htmltieties(result->name);?></a><br>
<a><?php echo $Snama;?> </a>
```

Comment: You need to write session_start(); at top of every page where you can use session

Comment: Please do not switch off error reporting with `error_reporting(0);`. You need errors!

Comment: Typo: `result->name`

Comment: Please clean-up your code. 1. htmlieties -> htmlentities 2. where do you add data to $_SESSION['alogin'] 3. You send the var edit to view-data.php but you never $_GET['edit'].
Essentiell parts are missing - I'm not quite sure where to search ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make "session_start();" reachable for all page or add it on each page

Comment: yeah i have done.. input that session. but it can't show data